# Having problems understanding BeautifulSoup filtering

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Could someone please explain how the filtering works with Beautiful Soup. Ive got the below HTML I am trying to filter specific data from but I cant seem to access it. Ive tried various approaches, from gathering all `class=g`'s to grabbing just the items of interest in that specific div, but I just get None returns or no prints.

Each page has a `<div class="srg">` div with multiple `<div class="g">` divs, the data i am looking to use is the data withing `<div class="g">`. Each of these has
multiple divs, but im only interested in the `<cite>` and `<span class="st">` data. I am struggling to understand how the filtering works, any help would be appreciated.

I have attempted stepping through the divs and grabbing the relevant fields:

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)   

 main = soup.find('div', {'class': 'srg'})
 result = main.find('div', {'class': 'g'})
 data = result.find('div', {'class': 's'})
 data2 = data.find('div')
 for item in data2:
     site = item.find('cite')
     comment = item.find('span', {'class': 'st'})

 print site
 print comment
```

I have also attempted stepping into the initial div and finding all;

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text) 

 s = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 's'})

 for result in s:
     site = result.find('cite')
     comment = result.find('span', {'class': 'st'})

 print site
 print comment
```

**Test Data**

```
<div class="srg">
    <div class="g">
    <div class="g">
    <div class="g">
    <div class="g">
        <!--m-->
        <div class="rc" data="30">
            <div class="s">
                <div>
                    <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap">
                        <cite class="_Rm">http://www.url.com.stuff/here</cite>
                    <span class="st">http://www.url.com. Some info on url etc etc
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--n-->
    </div>
    <div class="g">
    <div class="g">
    <div class="g">
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

After Alecxe's solution I took another stab at getting it right but was still not getting anything printed. So I decided to take another look at the `soup` and it looks different. I was previously looking at the `response.text` from `requests`. I can only think that `BeautifulSoup` modifies the `response.text` or I somehow just got the sample completely wrong the first time (not sure how). However Below is the new sample based on what I am seeing from a `soup` print. And below that my attempt to get to the element data I am after.

```
<li class="g">
<h3 class="r">
    <a href="/url?q=url">context</a>
</h3>
<div class="s">
    <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
        <cite>www.url.com/index.html</cite> #Data I am looking to grab
        <div class="_nBb">‎
            <div style="display:inline"snipped">
                <span class="_O0"></span>
            </div>
            <div style="display:none" class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1">
                <ul>
                    <li class="_Ykb">
                        <a class="_Zkb" href="/url?/search">Cached</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="st">Details about URI </span> #Data I am looking to grab
```

**Update Attempt**

I have tried taking Alecxe's approach to no success so far, am I going down the right road with this?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

for cite in soup.select("li.g div.s div.kv cite"):
    span = cite.find_next_sibling("span", class_="st")

    print(cite.get_text(strip=True))
    print(span.get_text(strip=True))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to deal with the hierarchy manually - let `BeautifulSoup` worry about it. Your second approach is close to what you should really be trying to do, but it would fail once you get the `div` with `class="s"` with no `cite` element inside.

Instead, you need to let `BeautifulSoup` know that you are interested in specific elements containing specific elements. Let's ask for `cite` elements located inside `div` elements with `class="g"` located inside the `div` element with `class="srg"` - `div.srg div.g cite` [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) would find us exactly what we are asking about:

```
for cite in soup.select("div.srg div.g cite"):
    span = cite.find_next_sibling("span", class_="st")

    print(cite.get_text(strip=True))
    print(span.get_text(strip=True))
```

Then, once the `cite` is located, we are "going sideways" and grabbing the next `span` sibling element with `class="st"`. Though, yes, here we are assuming it exists.

For the provided sample data, it prints:

```
http://www.url.com.stuff/here
http://www.url.com. Some info on url etc etc
```

---

The updated code for the updated input data:

```
for cite in soup.select("li.g div.s div.kv cite"):
    span = cite.find_next("span", class_="st")

    print(cite.get_text(strip=True))
    print(span.get_text(strip=True))
```

---

Also, make sure you are using the 4th `BeautifulSoup` version:

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

And the import statement should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: facepalm! bs4 was the fix! and of course my filtering wasnt spot on but once it was the fix was bs4

Answer (score 2):

First get `div` with class name `srg` then find all div with class name `s` inside that `srg` and get text of that `site` and `comment`. Below is the working code for me-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="srg">
    <div class="g">
    <div class="g">
    <div class="g">
    <div class="g">
        <!--m-->
        <div class="rc" data="30">
            <div class="s">
                <div>
                    <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap">
                        <cite class="_Rm">http://www.url.com.stuff/here</cite>
                    <span class="st">http://www.url.com. Some info on url etc etc
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--n-->
    </div>
    <div class="g">
    <div class="g">
    <div class="g">
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
labels = soup.find('div',{"class":"srg"})

spans = labels.findAll('div', {"class": 'g'})

sites = []
comments = []

for data in spans:
    site = data.find('cite',{'class':'_Rm'})
    comment = data.find('span',{'class':'st'})
    if site:#Check if site in not None
        if site.text.strip() not in sites:
            sites.append(site.text.strip())
        else:
            pass
    if comment:#Check if comment in not None
        if comment.text.strip() not in comments:
            comments.append(comment.text.strip())
        else: pass

print sites
print comments
```

Output-

```
[u'http://www.url.com.stuff/here']
[u'http://www.url.com. Some info on url etc etc']
```

EDIT--

Why your code does not work

For try One-

You are using `result = main.find('div', {'class': 'g'})` it will grab single and first encountered element but first element has not `div` with class name `s` . So the next part of this code will not work.

For try Two-

You are printing `site` and `comment` that is not in the print scope. So try to print inside for loop.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser') 

s = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 's'})

for result in s:
    site = result.find('cite')
    comment = result.find('span', {'class': 'st'})
    print site.text#Grab text
    print comment.text
```

Comment: Thanks although this doesnt help explain why it works and why mine doesnt :(

Comment: Is there a way to not need to step through the hierarchy of divs to get to the data? Mine still isnt working and I think its because I left out quite alot of html from the sample (purely to try keep it simple) as there is ALOT of data. But I am only interested in the the data as sampled.