# BeautifulSoup4 output with JS Filters

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Newbie here. I'm trying to scrape some sports statistics off a website using BeautifulSoup4. The script below does output a table, but it's not actually the specific data that appears in the browser (the data that appears in browser is the data I'm after - goalscorer data for a season, not all time records).

```
#import libraries
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#specify the url
stat_page = 'https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/goals?se=79'

# query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
page = urlopen(stat_page)

#parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
stats = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'statsTableContainer'})
name = stats.text.strip()
print(name)
```

It appears there is some filtering of data going on behind the scenes but I am not sure how I can filter the output with BeautifulSoup4. It would appear there is some Javascript filtering happening on top of the HTML.

I have tried to identify what this specific filter is, and it appears the filtering is done here.

```
<div class="current" data-dropdown-current="FOOTBALL_COMPSEASON" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="dd-FOOTBALL_COMPSEASON" data-listen-keypress="true" data-listen-click="true">2017/18</div>
```

I've had a read of the below link, but I'm not entirely sure how to apply it to my answer (again, beginner here).

[Having problems understanding BeautifulSoup filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944824/having-problems-understanding-beautifulsoup-filtering)

I've tried installing, importing and applying the different parsers, but I always get the same error (Couldn't find a Tree Builder). Any suggestions on how I can pull data off a website that appears to be using a JS filter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these cases, it's usually useful to track the network requests using your browser's developer tools, since the data is usually retrieved using AJAX and then displayed in the browser with JS.

In this case, it looks like the data you're looking for can be accessed at:

```
https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/stats/ranked/players/goals?page=0&pageSize=20&compSeasons=79&comps=1&compCodeForActivePlayer=EN_PR&altIds=true
```

It has a standard JSON format so you should be able to parse and extract the data with minimal effort.

However, note that this endpoint requieres the `Origin` HTTP header to be set to `https://www.premierleague.com` in order for it to serve your request.